# merge annotations into one

Tags: java, cdi

I want to build an annotation which inherits from all other predefined annotations:

```
@Inherited
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@JsonbNillable(value = true)
public @interface Domain {
}
```

Now I want to make use of this:

```
// domain annotation should inherit annotation @Getter, @Setter, @NoArgsConstructor, @JsonbNillable(value = true) 
@Domain 
public class User{


}
```

**However, the code above is not supported by JAVA.**

How can I do such things in JAVA? Is it possible with CDI or plain JDK?

I can use **CDI Stereotype**:

```
@Stereotype
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@JsonbNillable(value = true)
@Target({ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Domain {
}
```

However, some annotations are not supported for this kind. For example, `@Getter` is only supported on a class, an enum, or a field. How can I circumvent such things?

If I have a abstract class with defined annotations:

```
@Stereotype
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@JsonbNillable(value = true)
public abstract class Model{

}
```

and use that class, then annotations are not inherited, because there are annotations which cannot be @Inherited..

```
public class User extends Model{

}
```

How can I merge annotations into one, so I can use only one annotation? Is it possible in JAVA 12?

Comment: Stereotypes https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/enterprise/inject/Stereotype.html

Comment: @bakero98 good hint, however, does not work for all annotations..